# How to install and run npm jasmine locally

Tags: npm, jasmine, installation, global, local

Installing some npm packages globally is evil sometimes.
I don't want to install jasmine like that:

```
npm install -g jasmine
```

How can I install and use jasmine without **-g** attribute?

Comment: Installing global npm packages isn't necessarily evil. For some packages, you actually want to use a global install, for example `yo`. Whether to install a package globally or locally is completely subjective.

Comment: In general, packages used across applications should be globally installed and specific ones should be local. Applies to any tool you use..

Comment: @NitinSingh Quick nitpick here: The [Jasmine docs recommend you **don't** install it globally](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html):  "_[A global install] is not recommended, however, since it’s difficult to keep the globally installed jasmine version in sync with each project that uses it._" Subjective advice? Fair. `;^)` But probably also the voice of experience.

Comment: On local machine, if u chose to upgrade a package, you usually update it across all projects one is working on.. and if you are working on too many projects, its  a challenge of a different aspect to tackle :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1) You need to init an npm project. On the 5-th step of the wizard (question **test command:**) input **jasmine**

```
npm init
```

1b) If you init npm project before, make sure you have these lines in your **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jasmine"
},
```

2) Install jasmine as a local dependency

```
npm i --save-dev jasmine
```

3) To init jasmine (alternative for global **jasmine init**)

```
npm test init
```

4) To create example tests (alternative for global **jasmine examples**)

```
npm test examples
```

5) To run tests (alternative for global **jasmine**)

```
npm test
```

--
P. S. Save your global environment :)

Comment: You asked a question and answered it yourself at same moment ?

Comment: @NitinSingh Perfectly acceptable and even encouraged if the answer is not available yet.